# Is there a way in Eigen to evaluate multiple expressions at once?

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a way in Eigen to evaluate multiple expressions accessing the same input matrices in single pass?
In other ways can we write code equivalent to the following, but so that it only accesses a and b once?

```
MatrixXd a,b,c,d;
c=a+b;
d=a-b;
```

The example above runs slower than writing a loop myself:

```
for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
    c(i)=a(i)+b(i);
    d(i)=a(i)-b(i);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making concatenating matrices by blocks e.g. adding  [ A | A ] + [ B | -B ] ?

Comment: As far as I know Eigen does not have a concatenate expression. So concatenation is only possible by making a copy, which I am sure would be slower than directley using matrices.

Anyway that was just a small example of what I want to do. In practice I have a variety of operations, not just addition and subtraction.